# Load fail directory file in XmlReader .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, xmlreader

This filename has character is  (0xE700).

when i read in XmlReader, i can't read it because the file name load changes character is %EE%9C%80

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings);
```

Why  (0xE700) => %EE%9C%80!

Comment: Are you sure it is the filename and not the contents of the file?

Comment: yes! this is filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens since `XmlReader.Create` treats first parameter as Uri. This is not obvious but you can get it from the method signature

```
XmlReader Create(string inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext);
```

0xE700 is a special character that can't be used in the Uri and is escaped to `%EE%9C%80!`

However you can change the code and read the file content using `FileStream` e.g.

```cs
var fileName = string.Format("{0}test.xml", char.ConvertFromUtf32(0xE700));
File.WriteAllText(fileName, "<root><node /></root>");
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream))
        reader.ReadStartElement();
}
```

`new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)` will read file by name and will not encode the file name (as XmlReader.Create does).

Comment: Thanks you! I have found the same handling problem as you suggested